# Generics new keyword with inheritance

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I need to only only allow types inherited from the Person class to be used with this method. is this a valid way of doing this?

```
public static void Add<T>(T item) where T : Person, new()
{}
```

Comment: Why don't you try passing various types, some that are people and some that aren't, and see what happens?

Comment: Are you saying you don't want to allow instances of the `Person` type, but all derived types? This is not possible at compile time. `new()` won't give you that.

Comment: @Sebastian Unless `Person` doesn't have a default constructor; then it would.

Comment: @Servy: Good point! Although I somehow doubt that was the OP's intention ;-)

Comment: I need it to be strongly typed and only allow types inherited from the Person class which have a constructor with no parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Person` constraint satisfies the condition that only a object of type `Person` (or one of it's subclasses) can be used with this method. The constructor constraint (`new`) ensures that the provided type has a public, parameterless constructor. It is only necessary when your method invokes a constructor on the class.

For example:

```
public static void Add<T>(T item) where T : Person, new()
{
    var newItem = new T();
    ...
}
```

Here the `new` constraint is needed because of the line `new T()`. If the method doesn't contain a call to a constructor like that, you do not need to include the `new` constraint.

If you wanted to ensure that only objects whose types are subclasses of `Person` can be used with this method and not objects of type `Person`, you could either make `Person` abstract or make sure that it does not have a public, parameterless constructor (subclasses would have to provide one in order to be used with this method).

**Further Reading**

- [Constraints on Type Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely.  You have defined a static method that allows any class that inherits from Person and has a default constructor to be passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In the statement:

```
where T : Person, new()
```

`Person` specifies that `T` must be a type that can be cast to type `Person`

`new()` specifies that `T` has a default constructor and therefore your method would be able to do `new T()`

So if all you want is for `T` to be a `Person`, the first part of the constraint is enough. If you want to be able to create new instances, then you also need the second part.

PS. When in doubt about some syntax-related issue, don't hesitate to write a quick test; it will only help to understand the language better. Personnally, I like to use [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) to write quick tests.